# This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur

Tags: android

I have created as asynctask inside a method. But it shows a warning.

> This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur (anonymous
>   android.os.AsyncTask) less.. A static field will leak contexts. 
>   Non-static inner classes have an implicit reference to their outer
>   class. If that outer class is for example a Fragment or Activity, then
>   this reference means that the long-running handler/loader/task will
>   hold a reference to the activity which prevents it from getting
>   garbage collected.  Similarly, direct field references to activities
>   and fragments from these longer running instances can cause leaks. 
>   ViewModel classes should never point to Views or non-application
>   Contexts.

How can I avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0):

what this warning is trying to say, is that you can leak your activity/fragment in your phones memory.

if you create an AsyncTask that uses an activity context or the AsyncTask is and child of the activity/fragment, you keep the activity/fragment in memory. When you rotate or change activity in the periode the AsyncTask is running. you keep your old activity instance in memory and are leaking the activity/fragment.